# Intent from an activity to another containing Tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appcompat

I am trying to access an activity which has 3 tabs i.e. 3 fragments. I passed an intent to open that activity but the app stops as soon as i click it. What am i doing wrong? 
here is the intent.

```
 public void Registernow() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Payment.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

and here is my code for the activity i am trying to access.

```
public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);            //assigns viewpager to tablayout
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {       //defines number of tabs by setting appropriate fragment and tab name
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Recharge(), "RECHARGE");
        adapter.addFragment(new Bill(), "BILL");
        adapter.addFragment(new Transfer(), "TRANSFER");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);                      //custom adapter class provides fragments required for the view pager.
    }


}
```

i am mentioning the error that i got while debugging the app. This happens as soon as i click the button.

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.aadesh.saptrishi, PID: 25817
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aadesh.saptrishi/com.example.aadesh.saptrishi.Payment}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:199)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
                  at com.example.aadesh.saptrishi.Payment.onCreate(Payment.java:35)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please include the stacktrace containing the error

Comment: What your error says ? Have you registered your _Payment_ activity to manifest file?

Comment: Whats the error?? mension it !

Comment: stacktrace containing the error

Comment: i have mentioned the error guys, i dont really know what it means. i am pretty new.

Comment: Just google with your error you will get solution. Your stacktrace gives you solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application Theme should extend from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` in order to use the `Toolbar` as an `ActionBar`

Comment: it worked, i can't believe all i had to was this small change. Thanks a lot man you are a legend.